# Exe doesn't start with double click but does in CMD

Tags: windows

I moved to a new laptop for work. I don't have rights to install software but I can use portable apps. I often use Python to do things and on my previous laptop I used WinPython for that. I have downloaded and extracted WinPython on my new laptop but now when I click the executable it does not run, nothing happens. The same is true for VS Code. But then Git cmd portable does work without issue.

When I tried to execute the executable from the command line both Python's IDLE and VS Code ranwithout issue. What is going here?

Comment: Boot? Do you mean it does not run? Also, have you spoken w/ your IT staff? If executables aren't running, they should be informed and will likely have the correct fix.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't run. I have not yet spoken with them. Because I wanted to do some work this weekend but they aren't working :-)

Comment: What diagnostics have you attempted? Have you opened Task Manager and watched what happens when you double-click on the applications? What about checking the Event Viewer?

Comment: Try to right-click the executable and choose Properties. If you have the option to click "Unblock", do so.

Answer (score 1):

I put the files in the "My Documents" folder. When I moved them one level up into my user folder everything worked fine.